# DatePickerDialog has blacked out buttons in androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-alertdialog, android-jetpack

This simple class:

```
class DateSelectionDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val dayOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        return DatePickerDialog(requireContext(), this, year, month, dayOfMonth)
    }
}
```

results in strangely behaving buttons. What's important I didn't specify any style for the dialog. The `DialogFragment` is from `androidx.fragment.app` package.

[image: Dialog]

Comment: change the accent color or style of your calendar

Comment: The buttton text color will be changed too, making it invisible again.

Comment: Can you explain what you want ?

Comment: Don't u see that `Cancel` and `OK` buttons have the same color of text and background?

Comment: those two buttons are default dialog buttons right? did you check on the line of universal style or theme.

Comment: Right, I use only this code above.

Comment: Can you show us more code with your style and/or theme? I tried code you gave and it works just fine.

Comment: I'm extending `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar` for an activity. Have you used `DialogFragment` from `androidx`?

Comment: You're extending the theme for an activity but passing in a different context in your code. The `DialogFragment` has it's own lifecycle, but is dependent on the activity it's called from. I believe that might be the problem.

Comment: Since you are using the material components library use the [`MaterialDatePicker`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57807103/materialdatepicker-not-working-on-android/57808145#57808145). It works with the `Theme.MaterialComponents.*` theme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem comes from `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar`.

It's pretty new (and alpha) and it should replace `Theme.Design.Light.NoActionBar` but as we can see, it's not good enough yet.

**Your solution would be to just use `Theme.Design.Light.NoActionBar`.**

But if you *really* want to use `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar`... The problem is caused by this setting in theme:

```
<item name="viewInflaterClass">com.google.android.material.theme.MaterialComponentsViewInflater</item>
```

You could replace it with another `*ViewInflater` and there is not much choice but:

```
<item name="viewInflaterClass">androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater</item>
```

It works, but **I would not rely on it too much,** as using Inflater from another package might cause weird issues.

Answer (score 4):

I've been trying to figure this one out for weeks now; I just stumbled upon a solution a few days ago but I forgot where. Here's what you do; in your `styles.xml` file add a new style:

```
<style name="DatePickerStyle" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorSecondary</item>
    <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton</item>
</style>
```

Where `@color/colorSecondary` is your secondary color you're using in your `AppTheme`. Now in your `AppTheme` add the following item:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
   ...
   ...
   <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/DatePickerStyle</item>
</style>
```

This finally solved it for me. I hope this helps! My best guess is that this is a bug in the new `Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar`.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't change any styles, my best guess is it has something to do with the way Kotlin is deriving the context in this line:

`return DatePickerDialog(requireContext(), this, year, month, dayOfMonth)`

For Java you would call the DatePickerDialog as such:

`return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);` [android docs reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers#ShowingTheDatePicker)

I'm no expert on Kotlin, but a Java to Kotlin converter I used [here](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Examples/Hello,%20world!/Simplest%20version/Simplest%20version.kt) returned the Kotlin as this line:

`return DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day)`

The normal DatePickerDialog doesn't display the 'ok' and 'cancel' buttons with the default button background color. It displays a white background and sets the button text to that default color.

I think your code is somehow deriving the context of your button styles from the parent activity or default of your app, which would match the background color of the buttons to the main style instead of the date picker's normal overwrite to a white background.

My best guess is because you are using the new `requireContext()` and `requireActivity()` methods [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment#requireactivity); however, why are you using context instead of activity? Try `requireActivity()` instead:

`return DatePickerDialog(requireActivity(), this, year, month, dayOfMonth)`

After trying this line and/or `getActivity()` as shown above, please update.

Comment: I might be wrong, but current context and current activity is the same thing in this case? I replaced `requireContext()` with `requireActivity()` but nothing changed.

Comment: You might be right, but since a fragment has it's own lifecycle methods, I thought it was worth a try. The current activity and current context isn't always the same; however, I thought this might be the case because the styling of the buttons seemed to be inheriting from a different than style than the default. Glad you found your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Dialog will take you ***colorAccent*** property from `colors.xml` file, so check that's value, or you can specify or modify your dialog style by creating your custom style in style.xml file

Comment: Notice that colorAccent will change button's text color and background, making it invisible again.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Moi Janki. The solution on my end involved having to include the colorPrimary so that the text in the buttons would match the theme. See below;
colorAccent changes the highlight and the date selector color:

My DatePicker style was as follows:

```
<!-- Date Picker Style -->
<style name="MyDatePicker" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog</item>

</style>
```