# MaterialDatePicker not working on Android

Tags: java, android, material-design, androidx, material-components-android

I want to change the date picker of my project to the date picker provided by the Material Components for Android, but it is not working.

This is the code I've tried:

```
MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Long> builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();

MaterialDatePicker<Long> picker = builder.build();

picker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), picker.toString());
```

This is how it looked like:

[image: first image]

An this is how it should've looked like:

[image: second image]

Can anybody tell me what's missing?

Thanks

Comment: Hi your expected result image is missing, please fix it and we will do our best to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was in the colorPrimary.

The default color of my project to colorPrimary was "white" and the Material Date Picker style uses that colorPrimary to color the background and the text of the buttons. Since the color of the header text was also white, it appear that there was nothing there when there was everything.

I solved it by importing the styles file to my project and making some adjustments to the styles in my project.

Thank you all for your answers, all of them helped in finding the problem!

Comment: Please share the changes. Did you change your `primaryColor` to something else other than white?

Answer (score 24):

With the [Material Components for Android](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Picker.md) you can use the new [**`MaterialDatePicker`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Picker.md).

To work fine, in your app you have to use a [**Material Components Theme**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#4-change-your-app-theme-to-inherit-from-a-material-components-theme).
In this way you inherit the style and theme for the pickers.

To select a **single date** just use:

```
MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Long> builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();
builder.setTitleText(R.string.your_text);
MaterialDatePicker<Long> picker = builder.build();
picker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), picker.toString());
```

To select a **range date** you can use a DateRange Picker using:

```
MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Pair<Long, Long>> builder =
                    MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker();
CalendarConstraints.Builder constraintsBuilder = new CalendarConstraints.Builder();
builder.setCalendarConstraints(constraintsBuilder.build());
MaterialDatePicker<?> picker = builder.build();
picker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), picker.toString());
```

[image]

**Check the colors** used in your theme.

These attributes define your style. You **don't need** to add them, they are provided by default with the Material Components theme.

```
<!-- Picker styles and themes. -->
<item name="materialCalendarStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar</item>
<item name="materialCalendarFullscreenTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Fullscreen</item>
<item name="materialCalendarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar</item>
```

Based on these style, the colors used by the picker are:

```
HeaderLaoyout     -> background:colorPrimary, textColor:colorOnPrimary
HeaderSelection   -> background:colorPrimary, textColor:colorOnPrimary
ConfirmButtons    -> background:colorPrimary, textColor:colorOnPrimary
Buttons           -> background:colorPrimary, textColor:colorOnSurface
HeaderToggleButton->                          textColor:colorOnPrimary
Day               ->                          text:colorOnSurface  stroke:colorOnSurface
SelectedDay       -> background:colorPrimary, textColor:colorOnPrimary
RangeFillColor    -> background:colorPrimary
```

Comment: how do I setup a theme for this? Mine is showing blank in positive/negative buttons and title, accent, etc.

Comment: You have to use a [Material theme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#4-change-your-app-theme-to-inherit-from-a-material-components-theme) in your app as described in the doc. The styles in the answer are the default in all material themes.

Comment: How can we declare the picker in XML layout file instead of programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my primary color being white.

The simple solution is to override the `primaryColor` in the Calendar style:

**Base Theme:**

```xml
<style name="Base.Theme.YV.Bible" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
  <item name="materialCalendarStyle">@style/Theme.YV.Bible.DatePicker</item>
  <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/Theme.YV.Bible.DatePicker</item>
</style>
```

**Calendar / Datepicker Theme**

```xml
<style name="Theme.YV.Bible.DatePicker" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
  <item name="colorPrimary">?colorPrimaryDark</item> // this is the key, we need to use a dark color instead of our theme's primary color
</style>
```

**Usage**

```kotlin
val picker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder
    .datePicker()
    .setCalendarConstraints(CalendarConstraints.Builder().setStart(now().time).build())
    .setSelection(c.timeInMillis)
    .setTheme(com.bible.base.R.style.Theme_YV_Bible_DatePicker)
    .build()
picker.show(fragmentManager, null)
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting your desired output, make sure to add this before calling `show()`:

```
builder.setTitleTextResId(R.string.your_text);
// Where R.string.your_text must be equal to "Selected Date" or whatever you want
```

For Material DatePicker specifically, you need to first implement the latest library

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09'
```

Then

```
  MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Long> builder = 
                        MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();
  builder.setTitleTextResId(R.string.your_text);
  MaterialDatePicker<Long> picker = builder.build();
  picker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), picker.toString());
```

You can also simply show the [DatePickerDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog) instead of using Builder. The Dialog is 
For showing dialog and getting selected data:

```
EditText date;
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;

// Calendar object to hold the selected data
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR); // current year
int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); // current month
int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // current day
// date picker dialog
datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                // set day of month , month and year value in the edit text
                date.setText(dayOfMonth + "/"
                        + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);

            }
        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
datePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: I have the last library implemented and it still doesnt work.

Comment: DatePickerDialog doesn't support ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Add latest dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'

MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Long> builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();
       builder.setTitleTextResId(R.string.your_text);// here is the title for your datepicker
       MaterialDatePicker<Long> picker = builder.build();
       picker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), picker.toString());
```

Other options:
https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker

Comment: you can check it on Google's Maven Repository. [Google's Maven Repository](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html)                                                     com.google.android.material > material >1.1.0-alpha10