# How to use MaterialDatePicker in andoird

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, android-datepicker, material-components-android

I want to use new `MaterialDatePicker` in my app

I have used below code to use `MaterialDatePicker`

```
val builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()
builder.setTitleTextResId(R.string.date_of_birth)
builder.setTheme(R.style.MyTimePickerDialogTheme)
val picker = builder.build()
picker.show(childFragmentManager, picker.toString())
```

But `MaterialDatePicker` is not working as excepted

below is my `dependencies`

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'
```

[image: **My current output**]

[image: **My expected output**]

Another issue I'm facing is i don't know how to get selected date

Can anybody help me to solve these issues

If need more information please do let me know. Thanks in advance. Your efforts will be appreciated.

**UPDATE** i have tried solution provided in  these post [MaterialDatePicker not working on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57807103/8112541)

Here is my `MyTimePickerDialogTheme`

```
<style name="MyTimePickerDialogTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="materialCalendarStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar</item>
    <item name="materialCalendarFullscreenTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Fullscreen</item>
    <item name="materialCalendarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar</item>
</style>
```

Here is my `AppTheme`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

I'm still getting same output

Comment: @yuvrajsinh The question is about the [`MaterialDatePicker`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Picker.md) not the `android.app.DatePickerDialog`

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti can please share demo how to use `materialCalendarStyle` i have added those `style` in my `AppTheme` still I'm getting same output Also i don't know how to get selected date

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti please check updated question

Comment: First of all you have to use a [`MaterialComponents.Theme`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#material-components-themes) in your App. the `materialCalendarStyle` is by default provided by it. You don't need to add theme.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti i'm already using `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar` please check updated question

Comment: You don't need to add them. These attributes are defined by default in the material theme attributes. Remove the line `builder.setTheme(R.style.MyTimePickerDialogTheme)`

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti i have removed `builder.setTheme(R.style.MyTimePickerDialogTheme)` but still getting same output is there something that i'm missing??

Comment: are you using the latest 1.1.0-alpha10 ?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yes, i'm using `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'`

Comment: Ok. I am checking the colors. For example in the header it is used:<item name="android:background">?attr/colorPrimary</item>. It explain your white header.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti thank you for your response if possible please post an answer so it can help me to understand and help other also

Comment: Ok.Thanks for the feedback.I will add some info about the colors, just the time to check. The issue is there.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti thank you if possible please reopen the question

Comment: I've updated the linked answer with the (main) colors used in the material calendar. Check with the colors defined in your app theme. It should be enough without reopening the question.