# Is there a method to initially display the Mobile Input Picker from the Material Design Picker?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, datepicker, material-design

From the Material Design documentation on [Pickers](https://material.io/components/pickers/#mobile-input-picker), how does one display the Mobile Input Picker first after a user clicks on the EditText? The current behavior is that the picker opens up a calendar view.

I'm currently using `"com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02"`

[Default View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox6pz.png)

[Desired View *after clicking the pencil edit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KKsi.png)

Comment: Your desired view must be the default behavior, how are you showing the picker?

Comment: @SujanPoudel I am using the MaterialDatePicker.Builder, CalendarConstraints.Builder, and MaterialDatePicker. I don't know how to go about theming or selecting an alternate view.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57807103/materialdatepicker-not-working-on-android/57808145#57808145