# Android Material Date Range Picker issue

Tags: android, material-design, android-datepicker

Using below repo: 
[MaterialDateRangePicker](https://github.com/heysupratim/MaterialDateRangePicker)

I would like to add functionality where after selection of date in "From", the selection should automatically jump to "TO" for date selection. Currently, user after selecting a date in "From" has to press "To" then select a date. This is to reduce user clicks. Any possibility of fixing this. 
This is my first question in here, so please pardon if anything is not as per rules.

[image: FROM SELECTION, AFTER SELECTING A DATE HERE, IT SHOULD JUMP TO "TO"]
[image: TO SELCTION]

Comment: You can try to use the [MaterialDatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57807103/materialdatepicker-not-working-on-android/57808145#57808145) included in the material components library. You can define a range date.

Comment: Thank you  @GabrieleMariotti for your reply, I finally found a workaround using [SmoothDateRangePicker](https://github.com/leavjenn/SmoothDateRangePicker) library from Github.